# C, split a floating point number into individual digits

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am working on a small electronics project at home using a PIC microcontroller 18F which I am programming with HiTech C18 that is going to be used for digital control of a bench power supply.

I have run into a problem which is that I have a floating point number in a variable lets say for example 12.34 and need to split it out into 4 variables holding each individual number so i get Char1 = 1, Char2=2 etc etc for display on a 4-way seven segment LED display. The number will always be rounded to 2 decimal places so there shouldnt be a need to track the location of the decimal point.

I am trying to avoid any rounding where possible above 2 decimal places as the displays are giving measurements of voltage/current and this would affect the accuracy of the readouts.

Any advice on how to get this split would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use an integer and call it centiVolts? The answers below are all fine, but I would think it would easier to turn the centiVolt integer into a float if you ever need, than to constantly keep breaking it up.

Comment: That had not crossed my mind, I could multiply the value by 100 and then since the decimal point position is controlled separately I can then just position it correctly to give the correct readout. In that case then the conventional way of obtaining each digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sprintf to put the value into a character array. And then pick out the digits from there.

You could convert the floating point value directly to text. Or you could multiply by 100, truncate or round to int, and then convert that to text.

Comment: Thanks David, I am going to try going down the route of multiplying it by 100 and then just positioning the decimal point. I wanted to avoid converting to text where possible as this data is being transmitted over and I2C bus and will require me to later convert it to hex.

Comment: Converting to decimal digits is indistinguishable from converting to decimal text

Answer (score 3):

Convert to `int` and then to a string.

```
float x;
int i = x*100;
// or i = x*100.0f + 0.5f is round to nearest desired.
if ((i < 0) || (i > 9999)) Handle_RangeProblem();
char buf[5];
sprintf(buf, "%04d", i);
```

In embedded applications, many compilers use the fixed format string to determine which parts of the *large* `printf()` code will be needed.  If code is all ready using `"%f"` else where, then a direct `sprintf("%f")` here is not an issue.  Otherwise using `%04d"` could result in significant space savings.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are stored in binary format comprised of a sign bit, mantissa, and exponent.  A floating point number may not exactly match a given decimal representation (because of the different base-10 for decimal from the base-2 storage of floating point).  Conversion of a floating point number to a decimal representation is a problem often assigned in beginning programming courses.

Since are only interested in two decimal places, and a limited range of values, you could use a fixed point representation of your value.  This would reduce the problem from conversion of a floating point to decimal into conversion of integer to decimal.

```
long
longround( float f )
{
    long  x;
    x = (long)((f*100)+.5); //round least significant digit
    return(x);
}

char*
long2char( char ca[], long x )
{
    int pos=0;
    char sign = '+';
    ca[pos] = '0';
    long v = x;
    if( v<0 ) {
        sign = '-';
        v = -v;
    }
    for( pos=0; v>0; ++pos )
    {
        ca[pos] = (v%10)+'0';
        v = v/10;
    }
    ca[pos++] = sign;
    ca[pos] = '\0'; //null-terminate char array
    //reverse string - left as exercise for OP
    return(ca);
}
```

If you have a problem where the largest value could exceed the range of values supported by long integer on your system, then you would need to modify the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given the stated stability of your decimal point: simply `sprintf()` float into a buffer with appropriate format specifier, then you have your 4 values in a string easily extracted into what ever `type` you need them to be in...

***Example***

```
float num = 12.1234456;
char  buf[6];

int main(void)
{
    char a[2], b[2], c[2], d[2];
    int  x, y, z, w;    

    sprintf(buf, "%0.2f", num);//capture numeric into string  
    //split string into individual values   (null terminate)
    a[0] = buf[0]; a[1]=0;
    b[0] = buf[1]; b[1]=0;
    //skip decimal point
    c[0] = buf[3]; c[1]=0;
    d[0] = buf[4]; d[1]=0;  

    //convert back into numeric discretes if necessary
    x = atoi(a);
    y = atoi(b);
    z = atoi(c);
    w = atoi(d);
}
```

There are certainly more elegant ways, but this will work...

Comment: To cope with values like 1.23, suggest "%05.2f" to avoid "1.23" and get "01.23".